# Correct way to write arrow function in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to do the following in ES6 JavaScript, but can't figure out the right syntax. The second .then() works well, but the first one, which should throw an error doesn't (the first part contains standard JS syntax)

```
 return fetch('/api/data.json', {
        credentials: 'same-origin'
     }).then(function(response) {
       if (!response.ok) {
         throw Error(response.statusText);
       }
       return response;
       })
       .then(response => response.json())
       ................
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Why these two thens?

Comment: How would introducing an arrow affect the behavior you're seeing though? The code you've posted looks fine. Unless you're expecting an Error to be thrown of course - because it won't, you need to add a `.catch` at the end to trap that error

Comment: it doesn't affect the result, but the code is written in arrow-style, so it looks better like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "magic" :) about it

```
   .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok) {
       throw Error(response.statusText);
     }
     return response;
   })
```

Comment: nice, thank you! I think I must have a typo in my code when I've tried :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for first `.then()`:

```
.then(response => !response.ok ? throw Error() : response)
```

Comment: This is invalid JavsScript. `throw` is a statement, not an expression.